# Golang. Cross Compiling for MIPS

Tags: go, compilation, mips

I have tried compiling my simply program:

```
func main(){fmt.Printf("Hello")}
```

to **MIPS architecture** on my PC wit 64 bit Debian Linux according to documentation

https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment

via using command

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=mipsle go build 
GOOS=linux GOARCH=mips go build
```

Every time I get the error:

> runtime/internal/sys compile
>
> unknown architecture "mipsle(mips)"

The interesting thing is, if a try using command:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=mipsle64 go build
```

The program was build.

Is it dependent on system OS on my PC ? How can I build a binary for MIPS or MIPSLE ?

Comment: Which version of Go are you using? For me all your examples work. What is the log output when you compile with `-v`?

Comment: version is `go version go1.6 linux/amd64`
compiling using command `GOOS=linux GOARCH=mipsle go  build -v` give me this same information as above nothing more :(

Comment: You realize that go 1.8 is out now, which means that 1.6 is over a year old right?

Comment: Yeah... That was is. Oldest version golang a update to 1.8 and every works

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, it could be solved by installing the newest version of Go.

Comment: I'm looking how to compile for this cpu: cpu model  : MIPS 34Kc V5.6

Comment: @TheHippo It is not off-topic just because it has a simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

Go 1.6 does not support MIPS or MIPSLE. 1.6 supports MIPS64(LE). 1.8 supports MIPS(LE).

From https://golang.org/doc/install/source:

> - amd64 (also known as x86-64)
>
>   - A mature implementation.
> - 386 (x86 or x86-32)
>
>   - Comparable to the amd64 port.
> - arm (ARM)
>
>   - Supports Linux, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD and Darwin binaries. Less widely used than the other ports.
> - arm64 (AArch64)
>
>   - Supports Linux and Darwin binaries. New in 1.5 and not as well exercised as other ports.
> - ppc64, ppc64le (64-bit PowerPC big- and little-endian)
>
>   - Supports Linux binaries. New in 1.5 and not as well exercised as other ports.
> - mips, mipsle (32-bit MIPS big- and little-endian)
>
>   - Supports Linux binaries. New in 1.8 and not as well exercised as other ports.
> - mips64, mips64le (64-bit MIPS big- and little-endian)
>
>   - Supports Linux binaries. New in 1.6 and not as well exercised as other ports.
> - s390x (IBM System z)
>
>   - Supports Linux binaries. New in 1.7 and not as well exercised as other ports.